# Need help for a certain question in python on reverse of a number and palindromes

Tags: python

Does anyone know how to check if a given number and the reverse of that number's sum is a palindrome and the number of steps it takes to get a palindrome?
Such as:

```
Step 1:   87 +    78 =  165
Step 2:  165 +   561 =  726
Step 3:  726 +   627 = 1353
Step 4: 1353 +  3531 = 4884
```

Where it takes four steps to get a palindrome
Here is the code:

```
n=int(input())
rev = 0
while(n > 0): 
    a = n % 10
    rev = rev * 10 + a 
    n = n // 10
steps=0
while n!=rev:
    n+=rev
    steps+=1
print(steps,n)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This is my code so far:

n=int(input())
rev = 0
while(n > 0): 
    a = n % 10
    rev = rev * 10 + a 
    n = n // 10
steps=0
while n!=rev:
    n+=rev
    steps+=1
print(steps,n)

Comment: Add what you have tried in the question to show your effort and the result.

Comment: I found the reverse of the given number and the sum of the 2 numbers. From there I need to check if the sum is a palindrome. From there you have to do the same for the sum of the result. Ex: 12+21 is not a palindrome, so you reverse the sum of those 2 and do the same thing. Thats the part I'm stuck on

Comment: You still need to add your code to the question.

Comment: OK, I added it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive function.

```
def fun(n, steps):
    sum = n + int(str(n)[::-1])
    if str(sum) == str(sum)[::-1]:
        return (sum, steps)
    else:
        return fun(sum, steps + 1)

print(fun(87, 1))
#(4884, 4)
```